# Better way to implement paging users

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using the 3.21.0 version of Microsoft.Graph in a .net 5.0 webapi project.

I'd like to provide the possibility to get users page by page but unfortunately the `Skip` method is not supported for user queries.

The only way to provide paging I found was this:

```cs
public class MyController()
{
  // Constructors and stuff like that
  
  public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> Get([FromBody] Filter filter)
  {
    var users = await client.Users
                            .Request()
                            .Filter($"startsWith(givenName, '{filter.Pattern}') or startsWith(surname, '{filter.Pattern}')")
                            .Top(filter.ItemsPerPage)
                            .GetAsync();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < filter.Page; i++)
    {
      if (users.NextPageRequest != null)
        users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
      else
      {
        users = null;
        break;
      }
    }

    return users;
  }

  // Additional methods
}
```

Is there a better way to reach the goal? Because everytime I call `GetAsync()` a request is made. The performance would be much better if I only had to call `GetAsync()` only once.

But as I mentioned before

```cs
var users = await client.Users
                        .Request()
                        .Filter($"startsWith(givenName, '{filter.Pattern}') or startsWith(surname, '{filter.Pattern}')")
                        .Skip(filter.Page * filter.ItemsPerPage)
                        .Top(filter.ItemsPerPage)
                        .GetAsync();
```

raises an exception, that `Skip`is not supported.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827223/unable-to-use-both-top-and-skip-on-drives-request-for-the-office-365-graph-api

Comment: Yes, not all ODATA parameters are supported by all endpoints, the /users endpoint for example doesn't support the $skip parameter. You can see the above workaround helps you move forward.

Comment: What workaround do you refer to?

Comment: As i updated earlier it's not supported. Look at the above SO thread shared by Sabir and see if it suits your scenario.

Comment: But that's the HTTP API not the .Net API. I don't want to use HTTP directly. My question was about the Microsoft.Graph.dll package.